# HTML: float left isn't working for all elements with *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, css-float

This is my HTML code:

```
<div *ngIf="symbol !== undefined">
    <p>Symbol</p>
    <div *ngFor="let symbol of symbols">
            <img *ngIf="symbol == 1" class="symbol" width="150" src="assets/minus.png">
            <img *ngIf="symbol == 2" class="symbol" width="150" src="assets/plus.png">
            <img *ngIf="symbol == 3" class="symbol" width="150" src="assets/mal.png">
            <img *ngIf="symbol == 4" class="symbol" width="150" src="assets/geteilt.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to see thy symbols next to each other.
Example:

```
[symbol] [symbol] [symbol] [symbol]
[symbol] [symbol] [symbol] [symbol]
[symbol] [symbol] [symbol] [symbol]
```

So my CSS file looks like this:

```
.symbol{
    float: left;
    margin:2%;
}
```

Usually when the same symbol is there twice in the end of a line (with a braek to the next line), there is a break to the next line (correct). But in the next line is only one symbol on the right side and a break. 
Example:

```
[symbol][symbol][symbol][symbol][symbol][symbol]

                                        [symbol]

[symbol][symbol][symbol][symbol][symbol][symbol]
```

Why?

Solution: My pictures have a different size. It was just 2px longer!

Comment: add symbols sample array

Comment: Please create full working code in https://stackblitz.com

Comment: @lisa Working fine here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w3njau

Comment: @prashant I checked it. It is working there but still not on my project. This always happend when I add margin: 2% in my CSS

Comment: @lisa Might be, try to provide the code in the stackblitz so I can reproduce an issue there

Comment: @prashant I created an example here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q6zzcy .You can see it, when in the first two rows are 4 pictures. In the 3rd row the pictures are on the right side

Comment: @Ngô  I created an example here stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q6zzcy .You can see it, when in the first two rows are 4 pictures. In the 3rd row the pictures are on the right side

Comment: @lisa Working fine `[Second Image is corrupted]` check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tledds)

Comment: @prashant I found my problem. My original pictures have different sizes. There were differents from around 2px. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Pictures need to be the exact same size. I had a difference from 2px!

Answer (score 0):

```css
.symbol{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div *ngIf="symbol !== undefined">
    <p>Symbol</p>
    <div *ngFor="let symbol of symbols" class="symbol">
            <img *ngIf="symbol == 1" width="150" src="assets/minus.png">
            <img *ngIf="symbol == 2" width="150" src="assets/plus.png">
            <img *ngIf="symbol == 3" width="150" src="assets/mal.png">
            <img *ngIf="symbol == 4" width="150" src="assets/geteilt.png">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried yours. I still have the same error. This always happend when I add the margin to my symbol in CSS. And just in cases where in my symbol Array are the same numbers when there is a line break

Comment: have you removed "symbol" class from images? and add the same "symbol" class on outer div of images. I think you missing something because flex should work for you.

Comment: I tried it again. Now I am getting each symbol below each other. But I need to have them next to each other.

Comment: use "flex-direction: row;" instead of "flex-wrap: wrap;". I think this can work for you.

Comment: still the same problem

Comment: can you please share the screenshot ?